# Modal Bootstrap and ng-repeat doesn't work for me

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a modal for my every name of my hotel in my list using ng-repeat unfortunatly it dosen't work for me.and Idon't understand where is exactly the problem. This is my code:

```
<table class="details" >                
            <tr>
                <td class="leftDetails">Hotel</td>
                <td class="rightDetails">
                <div   ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="hotelsData"  selected-model="hotelModel" ng-init="h=hotelModel"  extra-settings="hotelSettings" >
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>               
        </table>
<table class="details4">
<tr>
    <td class="leftDetails4">Add new link</td>
    <td class="rightDetails4"><span class="btn-gray" ><a href>Link this contact to...</a></span></td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td class="leftDetails4">Hotel</td>
    <td  class="rightDetails4" ng_repeat="hotel in hotelModel"  >
<a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{hotel}}</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                     <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" ng-click="deleteHotel()"></i>  
     </td>   
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**That's wrong!**

- First of all, you have to get the model out of the ng_repeat loop
  because the model for instance has an `ID` and there shouldn't be
  elements that has the same `ID` in the same page, so by doing a
  ng-repeat loop you'll create multiple modals with the same `ID`
- Second of all, you don't need multiple modals, you need just one, if
  you want to pass data to it, just insert a variable in the modal, and
  when you click on the row to trigger it you pass the data from the
  row to the modal, and voilà.
- Note: you're missing the `</table>` close tag, and you didn't use 
  for semantics wise,

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thinks for your response, Sletheren , I will try to correct that, but I don't understand the second one. Can you explain more or give an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: Alrighty, so the modal will be shared for all the schools (meaning we need only one modal) so we only need to put the modal in the bottom of our html, and we can trigger it when we want to render data inside it

Comment: I make the change but it still the same

Answer (score 0):

```
use $modal directive


requestModalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : 'views/modal/model.html',
        controller : ModalInstanceCtrl,   
        backdrop: 'static',
        scope : $scope     
}); 

function ModalInstanceCtrl($scope, $modalInstance) {
   $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancelModal = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}
```